# Self Join in SQL explanation

Tags: sql

How does self join work when I link the same columns of two tables?

For example, let the table be:

[image]

And my code is:

```sql
SELECT a.*,b.*
  FROM table a JOIN table b ON (a.id=b.id) AND (a.name=b.name)
```

What will happen internally when the table is SELF JOIN-ed and why?

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you; it makes it harder to. Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer. Tagging completely irrelevant technologies just wastes the time of the subject experts you attract that know nothing about the technology you are *actually* asking about. Either way, tag spam can easily end up attracting downvotes and also close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about.

Comment: I have removed all your tags, they were either completely unrelated or conflicted, and added the generic [[tag:sql]] tag. You will need to [edit] your question to retag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: As for your question, however, why not run the query and find out what the results are..?

Comment: also, there is literally a `EXPLAIN` keyword if you are interested in how the query execution happens

Answer (score 0):

Your sample of a self-join does not give justice to the intent.  Maybe this scenario will help better explain it.  You have a database with your company.  In it is a table of all employees and who that employee reports to (i.e., manager).  So, this is a table pointing to itself such as

```
Employee table
EmployeeID   Name    ManagerID
1            Adam    3
2            Mark    1
3            Sally   0
4            James   1
5            George  3
6            Jill    3
7            Tom     0
8            Brian   2
```

So, this shows a hierarchy of multiple levels.  For example, #8 Brian's manager is #2 Mark, but Mark's manager is #1 Adam, who finally reports to #3 Sally, but #5 George also reports directly to #3 Sally.  Make sense?

So now, a self-join might be something like

```
Select
      emp.EmployeeID,
      emp.Name,
      coalesce( mgr.Name, '(no manager)' ) as ReportsToManager
   from
      Employee emp
         LEFT JOIN Employee mgr
            on emp.ManagerID = emp.EmployeeID
```